# Index Match VBA to update on rows

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I have this code and I would like it to work on the next row till last row,

```vb
Sub Index_Match()
  Dim result As Variant
  Range("P3").Value = [INDEX('Sheet1'!K:K,MATCH(1,(L3='Sheet1'!G:G)\*(Q3='Sheet1'!J:J),0))]
  Debug.Print result
End Sub
```

The code has to update on every row.

```vb
  Range("P4").Value = [INDEX('Sheet1'!K:K,MATCH(1,(L4='Sheet1'!G:G)\*(Q4='Sheet1'!J:J),0))]
```

So on.....

Any help appreciated

Comment: `Range("P3:P100").Formula = "index('Sheet1'!$K:$K,MATCH(1,(L3='Sheet1'!$G:$G)*(Q3='Sheet1'!$J:$J),0))"`, `Range("P3:P100").Value = Range("P3:P100").Value`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Evaluate Index/Match Array Formula

```vb
Sub EvaluateIndexMatchFormula()

    ' Write the formula to a string first...    
    Dim Formula As String: Formula _
        = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet1'!K:K," _
        & "MATCH(1,(L3='Sheet1'!G:G)*(Q3='Sheet1'!J:J),0)),"""")"
    ' ... so you can test it with:
    'Debug.Print Formula
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' adjust!

    Dim drg As Range ' Destination Range

    With dws.UsedRange
        Set drg = dws.Range("P3", dws.Cells(.Rows.Count + .Row - 1, "P"))
    End With
    
    With drg
        ' Write formulae. 
        With .Cells(1)
            .FormulaArray = Formula
            .AutoFill drg, xlFillDefault
        End With
        ' Keep only values.
        .Value = .Value
    End With
 
End Sub
```